# Is it possible to build my own DDNS with Bind?

Tags: c#, c, delphi, dns, bind

I know that there are many dynamic DNS service providers (including free). But I would like to build my own DDNS.

I will buy a domain name(e.g. example.com), then create a series of sub-domain(user1.example.com, user2.example.com,...). I'll deploy my own DNS(maybe with Bind) and each sub-domain need resolve to dynmaic ip(for dial-up and cable modem customers).

The customer's pc will run my client program, it will notify my server program when the ip address changed.

My question is: How to communicate between my server program and the nameserver?

Comment: So, you're essentially asking how to programmatically configure Bind?

Comment: Yes. How could my program to notify the nameserver to dynamic update record?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it is possible and BIND has a protocol for sending dynamic changes to the server, I would advise against it. There are other authoritative nameserver implementations which can serve records from SQL databases, which should integrate much better with the tools you might want to use for letting customers make updates.

Comment: Here is a great list of DNS servers: http://www.maradns.org/dns_software.html The only one I see there that mentions authoritative DNS from an SQL source is MyDNS, but I'm almost sure I've seen others.